# How do I fix this error code on Thonny For Object Detection

Tags: opencv, gstreamer, object-detection, raspberry-pi4

I am using a raspberry pi camera in my code for object detection using OPENCV but this is my error code GStreamer warning: Error opening bin: unexpected reference "videofile" - ignoring

I checked if my camera is working but my raspberry Pi isn’t detecting it
But when I try the command libcamera-still -o test.jpg
It works perfectly fine
I even downloaded my GStreamer file

Comment: [mre] required. this looks like gstreamer is involved. -- add a tag for the language you're working in. [edit] your post to do it.